# How to check & confirm if dropzone is actually sending file to server

Tags: express, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, dropzone.js

I am using dropzonejs and using following code to initialize dropzone:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```

On the server side, I am using expressjs\nodejs & using following code:

```
fs.readFile(req.files.displayImage.path, function (err, data) {
  // ...
  var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/uploadedFileName";
  fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
    res.redirect("back");
  });
});
```

problem is req.files is always coming as undefined.

I want to know when we upload a file, is there a way through developertoolbar to check the payload & confirm whether file is been sent or not?

Comment: I'm guessing that file is being sent via AJAX or via regular POST with page reload. In both cases you should be able to see the upload request in the 'Network' tab. If page reloads after upload, simply check 'Preserve log' option in the Network tab.

Comment: @KonradDzwinel: The file is sent through ajax request. Can you please point out any specific key i must check in order to see the uploaded file?

Comment: Check out 'Request Payload': https://imgur.com/2qqn88a